# Getting error for printing text between two patterns in each line

Tags: shell, text, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file with following text

```
Query= gi_4849 ref_YP_00.1_ flagellar assembly protein H[Bacillus]--
Query= gi_4851 ref_YP_00.1_ MS-ring protein[Bacillus]--
Query= gi_4852 ref_YP_00.1_ flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE [Bacillus]--
Query= gi_4851 ref_YP_00.1_ [membrane protein][Bacillus]--
.
.
.
```

Desired output:

```
flagellar assembly protein H
MS-ring protein
flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE
[membrane protein]
.
.
.
```

I have tried following commands;

```
sed '/.1_/,/[Bacillus/p' filename > new
sed '/".1_"/,/"[Bacillus"/p' filename > new
awk '/.1_/,/[Bacillus/' filename > new
awk '/".1_"/,/"[Bacillus"/' filename > new
```

but `awk` is not working and `sed` is giving an error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated address regex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` this code does it:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*1_ (.*)\[Bacillus.*/\1/g' file
flagellar assembly protein H
MS-ring protein
flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE 
[membrane protein]
```

It fetches the lines and catches the matched group #1 for the block from `1_` to `[Bacillus` and then prints it back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but some of my text, which I wanted to extract is also in square brackets e.g. Query= gi_4851 ref_YP_00.1_ [membrane protein][Bacillus]--. For this type, I only wanted to extract membrane protein with square brackets.

Comment: Note that the answers we provide come from the input you show. If you then have different inputs, the answer may not match with your desired output. Hence, I suggest you to post a broad input so that people can answer properly.

Comment: @MuhammadSufian check updated answer with `sed`, it properly shows it now.

Comment: I don't think the leading space is wanted `sed -r 's/.*1_ (.*)\[Bacillus.*/\1/g' file` and for the trailing space `sed -r 's/.*1_ (.*\S)\s?\[Bacillus.*/\1/g' file`

Comment: Thanks @sudo_O, I didn't know that using `-r` I could catch the matched groups without escaping the `()`. Thanks also for pointing out the possibility to get rid off trailing spaces.

Comment: @fedorqui no problem, capture groups are part of ERE so don't need to be escaped when ERE is switched on with `-r`. Personally I try to avoid escaping as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to print partial line matches then with `GNU Grep` you could do:

```
$ grep -Po '_\s\K.*(?=[[])' file
flagellar assembly protein H
MS-ring protein
flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE 
[membrane protein]
```

Or more explicitly:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=ref_YP_00.1_ ).*(?=\[Bacillus]--)' file
flagellar assembly protein H
MS-ring protein
flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE 
[membrane protein]
```

And if you want to account for the optional trailing space:

```
$ grep -Po '_\s\K.*\S(?=\s?[[])' file 
flagellar assembly protein H
MS-ring protein
flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE
[membrane protein]

# OR

$ grep -Po '(?<=ref_YP_00.1_ ).*\S(?=\s?\[Bacillus]--)' file 
flagellar assembly protein H
MS-ring protein
flagellar hook-basal body proteinFliE
[membrane protein]
```

Comment: Your answer is also working for me, but some of my text, which I wanted to extract is also in square brackets e.g. Query= gi_4851 ref_YP_00.1_ [membrane protein][Bacillus]--. For this type, my desired output is [membrane protein].

Comment: That's kind of important! Make sure when posting a question to use representative examples. This is easily fixed, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/1_ (.*?)\[Bacillus*/)' your_file
```